# How to check weather an character is repeated in a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def check(inp, chk):
    if chk in inp:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")

inp = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
chk = input("Enter a character to check: ")

check(inp, chk)
```

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Enter a character to check: 1

No

When i give any character which is there in the list, it says no.

What's the error in this?

Comment: `input()` `return`s a string in Python 3, you need `chk = int(chk)`. Also this only checks if the character is in the input, not if it is repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve this via using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which returns a dict `object` with the count of each element in the iterator.

Below is the sample function to check repetition from a `Counter` object:

```
def check_repeatition(num, counter):
    count = counter.get(num)  # returns `None` if `num` not found
    if count == 1:
        print('Non repeated number')
    elif count == None:
        print('Number not found')
    else:
        print('Repeated Number')
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
#                 v           v  repeated
>>> my_num_str = '1 2 3 4 5 6 1 7 8 9'

# Convert number string to `list` of `int` numbers
>>> num_counter = Counter(map(int, my_num_str.split()))

# Two occurrence of `1` in the string
>>> check_repeatition(1, num_counter)
Repeated Number

# One occurrence of `2` in the string
>>> check_repeatition(2, num_counter)
Non repeated number

# `0` not present in the string
>>> check_repeatition(0, num_counter)
Number not found
```

---

***Issue with your code*** is that your are checking for the presence of the number in the list via using `in` operator. Your code is not checking for the repetition of the number. Also, you need to type-cast `chk` to `int` via using `chk = int(chk)` as `input(...)` returns `str` in Python 3.x

Comment: A `Counter` feels like overkill for this when you could just use `list.count()`

Comment: As mentioned by Chris, ff the count of a single element is required (for a one time), `list.count()` is better. But if the check is needed to be performed iteratively, `Counter` will be a better choice.